# What is the best way to perform a qcut for each unique date in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has an index named "Date". Which contains a large number of dates.
I want to group unique dates, and perform a qcut on a column for each unique date in the df.

The following code works fine for a small number of unique dates from the dataset. However when left to run over multiple years worth of dates. The code never completes.

Is there a better way?
Thanks

```
df['qcut_result'] = df.groupby("Date")["Column_to_qcut"].apply(pd.qcut, 10,['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'])
```

Comment: `groupby().apply`  does not vectorize across the groups, so what you see is expected. you can do `groupby().rank() / groupby().transform('size')` to get the quantile for all the rows, then you extract the quantiles you want from there.